# Having trouble displaying all info entered in GUI with python

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I am creating a GUI that has two different types on entry for info.  One is the checkbox and the other is the entry field.  I want to have the show button display both inputs but I cannot seem to make it work in one button.  I can change it to show one or the other.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong to make both inputs display from the same button.  Here is the code that I have.  Right now it will display the entry field information, not the checkbox

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


def show_entry_fields():
    print("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPhone Number: %s"% (e1.get(),e2.get(), e3.get()))


master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Personal Info")
Label(master, text="Your gender:").grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=W)


var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="male", variable=var1).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="female", variable=var2).grid(row=0, column = 2, sticky=W)
tk.Label(master, text="First Name").grid(row=1, pady=3)
tk.Label(master, text="Last Name").grid(row=2, pady=3)
tk.Label(master, text="Phone Number").grid(row=3, pady=3)


e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)
e3 = tk.Entry(master)


e1.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=3)
e2.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=3)
e3.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=3)


tk.Button(master, text='Quit', fg="red", command=master.quit).grid(row=4,column=0, sticky=tk.E, pady=10)
tk.Button(master, text='Show', fg="blue", command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.W, padx=50, pady=10)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Whats the problem using `var1.get()`?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're even attempting to display the value of the checkbutton. If you can change it to show one or the other, why don't you combine those two solutions into one function?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get just one output( male or female ) which is the logic here with gender input .. then you have to use `RadioButton` not `CheckButton`

so your code will be like that:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


def show_entry_fields():
    print("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPhone Number: %s\n gender: %s"% (e1.get(),e2.get(), e3.get(), var1.get()))


master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Personal Info")
Label(master, text="Your gender:").grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=W)


var1 = StringVar()
Radiobutton(master, text="male", variable=var1, value="male").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
Radiobutton(master, text="female", variable=var1, value="female").grid(row=0, column = 2, sticky=W)
tk.Label(master, text="First Name").grid(row=1, pady=3)
tk.Label(master, text="Last Name").grid(row=2, pady=3)
tk.Label(master, text="Phone Number").grid(row=3, pady=3)


e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)
e3 = tk.Entry(master)


e1.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=3)
e2.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=3)
e3.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=3)


tk.Button(master, text='Quit', fg="red", command=master.quit).grid(row=4,column=0, sticky=tk.E, pady=10)
tk.Button(master, text='Show', fg="blue", command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.W, padx=50, pady=10)

tk.mainloop()
```

but let's say you have a list of options like preferred languages for example and you want to get the output of what exactly the user chooses .. in that case you should use `ListBox`

everything you need to know about `ListBox` [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_listbox.htm)